# ¿Como ordenar alfabéticamente y de menor a mayor elementos de una lista enlazada doble?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

El día de hoy estoy realizando una practica de mi clase de algoritmos ya llevo la mayor parte del ejercicio solo que tengo dudas ya que en uno de los puntos debo ordenar los elementos por la descripción alfabéticamente y también ordenar por precio. 
He visto videos y parece sencillo pero al estar trabajando con estructuras y con elementos específicos de ellas se me complica un poco. ¿Alguna recomendación en que podría realizar? Las funciones donde hare esos dos procedimientos es "mostrarPrecio" y "mostrarDescripcion".

Por cualquier cosa aquí esta el código que llevo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct nodo{
char *dato; //Producto//
int number; //Precio//
int cantidadExistencia;
char *descripcion;
struct nodo *ant;
struct nodo *sig;
};
int numberVerification();
void validacionChar1(char *c);
void validacionChar2(char *c);
struct nodo *crearNodo(char *dato,int number,int cantidadExistencia,char 
*descripcion){
struct nodo *p;
p=(struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
p->dato=dato;
p->number=number;
p->cantidadExistencia=cantidadExistencia;
p->descripcion=descripcion;
p->sig=NULL;
p->ant=NULL;
return(p);
}

struct nodo *insertar(struct nodo *inicio, char *dato,int number,int cantidadExistencia,char *descripcion){
struct nodo *p, *q=NULL, *nuevo;
p=inicio;
nuevo=crearNodo(dato,number,cantidadExistencia,descripcion);
while(p!=NULL && (strcmp(p->dato,dato)>=0) && number>=p->number && cantidadExistencia>=p->cantidadExistencia && descripcion>=p->descripcion){
    q=p;
    p=p->sig;
}
printf("\nSe agrego satisfactoriamente!");
getch();
if(q==NULL){
    nuevo->sig=p;
    p->ant=nuevo;
    inicio=nuevo;
}
else{
    q->sig=nuevo;
    nuevo->ant=q;
    nuevo->sig=p;
    if(p != NULL){
        p->ant=nuevo;
    }
}
return(inicio);
}

void mostrarDescripcion(struct nodo *inicio){
struct nodo *aux;
char temp[100];
system("cls");
if(!inicio){
    printf("Esta vacia.");
}
else{
    aux=inicio;
    do{
        printf("Producto: %s\n",aux->dato);
        printf("Precio: %d\n",aux->number);
        printf("Cantidad en existencia: %d\n",aux->cantidadExistencia);
        printf("Descripcion del producto: %s\n\n",aux->descripcion);
        aux=aux->sig;
    }while(aux!=NULL);
}
getch();
}

void mostrarPrecio(struct nodo *inicio){
struct nodo *aux;
system("cls");
if(!inicio){
    printf("Esta vacia.");
}
else{
    aux=inicio;
    do{
        printf("Producto: %s\n",aux->dato);
        printf("Precio: %d\n",aux->number);
        printf("Cantidad en existencia: %d\n",aux->cantidadExistencia);
        printf("Descripcion del producto: %s\n\n",aux->descripcion);
        aux=aux->sig;
    }while(aux!=NULL);
}
getch();
}

 struct nodo *entradaSalida(struct nodo *inicio,char *dato,int cantidadExistencia,int dato2){
struct nodo *p, *q=NULL;
p=inicio;
while(p!=NULL && strcmp(p->dato,dato)!=0 && p->cantidadExistencia!=cantidadExistencia){
    q=p;
    p=p->sig;
}
if(q==NULL){
    p->cantidadExistencia = dato2;
    p = p->sig;
}
else{
    if(p!=NULL){
        p->cantidadExistencia = dato2;
        p = p->sig;
    }
    else{
        printf("No se encontro.");
        getch();
    }
}
return inicio;
 }

struct nodo *eliminar(struct nodo *inicio,char *descripcion){
struct nodo *p, *q=NULL;
p=inicio;
while(p!=NULL && strcmp(p->descripcion,descripcion) != 0){
    q=p;
    p=p->sig;
}
if(q==NULL){
    inicio=p->sig;
    inicio->ant=NULL;
    free(p);
}
else{
    if(p!=NULL){
        q->sig=p->sig;
        p->sig->ant=q;
        free(p);
    }
    else{
        printf("No se encontro.");
        getch();
    }
}
return inicio;
 }

void menu(){
struct nodo *inicio=NULL;
int opc;
int precio,cantidadExistencia,dato2;
char *producto, *descripcion;
do{
    system("cls");
    printf("1. Insertar producto.\n");
    printf("2. Eliminar producto por descripcion.\n");
    printf("3. Entrada/salida de un producto.\n");
    printf("4. Mostrar productos alfabeticamente por descripcion.\n");
    printf("5. Mostrar productos ordenados por cantidad ascendente.\n");
    printf("6. Salir.\n");
    printf("Opcion: [ ]\b\b");
    opc = numberVerification();
    switch(opc){
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            producto=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
            printf("Escribe el nombre del producto: ");
            //validacionChar1(producto);
            gets(producto);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nPrecio: ");
            scanf("%d",&precio);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Cantidad en existencia: ");
            scanf("%d",&cantidadExistencia);
            fflush(stdin);
            descripcion=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
            printf("Descripcion del producto: ");
            //validacionChar2(descripcion);
            gets(descripcion);
            fflush(stdin);

                if(inicio==NULL){
                    inicio=crearNodo(producto,precio,cantidadExistencia,descripcion);
                }
                else{
                    inicio=insertar(inicio,producto,precio,cantidadExistencia,descripcion);
                }
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            printf("Descripcion del producto a eliminar: ");
            validacionChar1(descripcion);
            inicio=eliminar(inicio,descripcion);
            fflush(stdin);
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            producto=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
            printf("Ingrese el producto: ");
            gets(producto);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nNueva cantidad de cantidad en existencia: ");
            scanf("%d",&dato2);
            fflush(stdin);
            entradaSalida(inicio,producto,cantidadExistencia,dato2);
            break;
        case 4:
            mostrarDescripcion(inicio);
            break;
        case 5:
            mostrarPrecio(inicio);
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
    }
}while(opc!=6);
}

void validacionChar1(char *c){ /*Validacion de caracteres*/
int i;
char key;
i=0;
c[0] = '\0';
do{
    key = getch();
    if(i>0 && key == 8){
        /*printf("\b \b");*/
        c[--i] = '\0';
    }
    else{
        if((key>=65 && key<=95) || (key>=97&&key<=122) || key ==32){
            printf("%c",key);
            c[i++]=key;
        }
    }
}while((key!=13 || c[0] == '\0')&&i<100);
c[i] = '\0';
}

void validacionChar2(char *c){ /*Validacion de caracteres*/
int i;
char key;
i=0;
c[0] = '\0';
do{
    key = getch();
    if(i>0 && key == 8){
        /*printf("\b \b");*/
        c[--i] = '\0';
    }
    else{
        if((key>=65 && key<=95) || (key>=97&&key<=122) || key ==32){
            printf("%c",key);
            c[i++]=key;
        }
    }
}while((key!=13 || c[0] == '\0')&&i<100);
c[i] = '\0';
}

 int numberVerification(){ /*Validacion de numeros enteros*/
int value = 0;
int acumulation = 0;
char caracter;
do{
    caracter = getch();
    if(caracter > 0x30 && caracter <= 0x39){
        putchar(caracter);
        value = (int)caracter-0x30;
        acumulation = (acumulation*10)+value;
    }
    if(caracter == 0x08){
        acumulation = acumulation/10;
    }
}while(caracter != 13);
return acumulation;
 }

int main(){
menu();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo ver en tu código, cuando le das a mostrar precio o mostrar descripcion lo que haces es recorrer la lista e imprimir sus valores, y basicamente las dos funciones son iguales, solo difieren en que en una usas una variable temp tipo char la cual no utilizas.

Por lo que basicamente te esta faltando el ordenamiento.

Existen muchos algoritmos de ordenamiento (quicksort, insertion sort, bubble sort, exsel sort ... ) por lo que en en primer lugar te recomiendo que elijas uno.

Supon que escojes insertion sort.

```
// Variables para controlar los punteros
struct nodo *aux = inicio;
struct nodo *temp;

// variables auxiliares para hacer el intercambio
char datoAux[100]; //Producto//
int precioAux; //Precio//
int cantidadAux;
char descripcionAux[100];

while ( aux != NULL )
{
    cursor = aux;
    while (cursor != inicio && cursor->number < cursor->ant->number )
    {
          // Mi segunda recomendación viene aca
          // cuando tienes que hacer el swap entre las estructuras
          // yo recomiendo que dejes los punteros tranquilos y te encargues
          // de intercambiar los valores

          // datosAux = cursor
          strcpy ( datoAux, cursor->dato); //Producto//
          precioAux = cursor->number; //Precio//
          cantidadAux = cursor->cantidadExistencia;
          strcpy( descripcionAux , cursor->descripcion);

          // cursor = cursor->ant 
          strcpy ( cursor->dato, cursor->ant->dato); //Producto//
          precioAux = cursor->ant->number; //Precio//
          cantidadAux = cursor->ant->cantidadExistencia;
          strcpy( cursor->descripcion, cursor->ant->descripcion );

          // cursor->ant = datosAux
          strcpy ( cursor->ant->dato, datoAux ); //Producto//
          cursor->ant->number = precioAux; //Precio//
          cursor->ant->cantidadExistencia = cantidadAux;
          strcpy( cursor->ant->>descripcion , descripcionAux );

          cursor = cursor->ant;
    }
    aux = aux->sig;
}
```

De esta forma comparas por precio, para comparar por decripcion en el while en ves de poner un menor que `(<)` colocas un `strcmp(,) < 0` entre las descripciones presente y anterior.

Saludos, espero que te sirva